# Hyperlink's click even not triggering in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my full JS code:

```
  var timeOutId;
    function ft(){
        $.get("progress.txt", null, function(data){
            if(data.substr(0,10) == "MSG::MSG::"){
                $("#box").html(data);
                window.clearTimeout(timeOutId);
            }else{
                $("#box").html(data);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#box").corner('20px');
        $("#progress").hide();
    });

    $("#newm").click(function(){
        $("#progress").show();
        $("#list").html = $.ajax({
            url: "action.php",
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: ({keyword : $("#keyword").value()},{format: $("#format").value()},{filename: $("#filename").value()},{list: $("#list").value()}),
            dataType: "html"
        });
        timeOutId = window.setTimeout("ft()", 10000);
    });
```

and there is a hyperlink with ID "newm" on page but clicking on the link doesnt trigger the ajax request. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I'm really wondering how did you realize you need to do some things on document.ready, but not this..

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt get what you said.

Comment: Try putting click under .ready()

Comment: I guess I should read the documentation a bit rather than just copy-paste. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

I have tryed your code and recognize that your binding to click is not working because the `DOM` element is not available at this time.

You should bind it under `$(document).ready()` to ensure the `DOM` is fully loaded before binding `javascript / jquery` to that.

This will enusre that your link will work, but its hard to help you without the `html` source.
If this will not help, please post the `html`.